# How to change the orientation of a brace?, with psbrace, in PsTricks

Tags: pstricks, braces, pstricks-add

I can´t believe it.

I was looking and reading... the multiple examples in page 23 in [pstricks-add-doc.pdf](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks-add/pstricks-add-doc.pdf)
and I can´t reach what I want. Even copying and pasting any examples of the PDF

I know how to put the the brace pointing UP.

But I try, and try, and I have no solution.

This is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,x11names]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-blur,pstricks-add}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\newpsobject{psframegray}{psframe}{fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur}
\definecolor{azultenue}{RGB}{65,170,193}
\definecolor{rojotenue}{RGB}{192,2,3}
\definecolor{naranjatenue}{RGB}{241,101,35}
\definecolor{verdetenue}{RGB}{144,169,61}
\definecolor{gris135}{RGB}{135,135,135}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
%\resizebox{8cm}{!}{
\psset{framearc=0.2, shadowcolor=black!70, shadowangle=-90, unit=1.0cm,nodesep=0.12cm}
%
\def\pscolhookii{\hskip 1cm}
\def\pscolhookiii{\hskip 1cm}
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=2.2, colsep=5.2]% defines the distance between two frames
 [name=Inicio]
 \psframegray(-2.5,-3.2)(2.5,2.5)
%
 \rput(-1.1,1.5){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=azultenue]{p1}{\textcolor{black}{$p_1$}}}
 \rput(-0.3,1.5){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=azultenue]{p2}{\textcolor{black}{$p_2$}}}
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.2,1.5)
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.4,1.5)
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.6,1.5)
  \rput(1.1,1.5){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=azultenue]{pmu}{\textcolor{black}{$p_\mu$}}}
%
\psbrace(-1.5,1.2)(1.5,1.2){}
\pnode(0,0.58){nfantasma}

%%%%%%%%%%% HOW TO PUT THIS BRACE POINTING UP  %%%%%%%%%% %%%%%%%%%% %%%%%%%%%% %%%%%%%%%% 
\psbrace(-2.1,-0.8)(2.1,-0.8){A}   %%%%%%%%%% 
%%%%%%%%%% %%%%%%%%%% %%%%%%%%%% %%%%%%%%%% %%%%%%%%%% %%%%%%%%%% %%%%%%%%%% 

\psbrace*[rot=90,ref=rC](-2.1,-1.8)(2.1,-1.8){AA}


\psbrace[rot=180,nodesep=-0.8cm](-2.1,-2.8)(2.1,-2.8){AAA}

\psbrace*[ref=lb](-1,1)(1,1){I}  %%% copy from the page 23. where you can see pointing UP

\pnode(0,-1.75){nfantasma2}
&[name=Conjunto]
 \psframegray(-2.5,-3.2)(2.5,2.5)
 \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gris135,linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red,linewidth=0.06cm,linearc=0.4](-2.4,-1.5)(-2.4,-0.5)(2.4,-0.5)(2.4,-1.5)(-2.4,-1.5)

&[name=EM]
\psframegray(-2.5,-3.2)(2.5,2.5)
\end{psmatrix}

\vspace{3.1cm}
\caption{Esquema $(\mu , \lambda)$}\label{mucomalambda-ilustracion}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A brace is simple drawn from a point A to a point B. If you want to change the orientation you have to change the way. So instead from A to B use B to A.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,x11names]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-blur,pstricks-add}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
 \psbrace(-1.5,1.2)(1.5,1.2){A}
 \psbrace(1.5,-1.2)(-1.5,-1.2){B}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank You very much :-))) I can´t belive,.. I was looking and loking, and reading, and I didn´t realized. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The global nodesep in row 18 changes the label in psbrace two, so you have to write explicite

```
\psbrace[ref=Ct,rot=90,nodesep=0](-2.1,-1.8)(2.1,-1.8){\fbox{AA}}
```

if you want to have the label centerd.